# kohana 3 image save and thumbnail

Tags: php, kohana, image-uploading

Hi I want to save an uploaded image as 2 versions (normal and thumbnail)

Here is the code I'm using for normal:

```
$picture = Upload::save($_FILES['picture']);
// Resize, sharpen, and save the image
Image::factory($picture)->resize(200, NULL)->save();
$profile->profile_picture = basename($picture);
```

This works, but I also want to create a smaller version to `$profile->profile_picture_thumb`.

I have tried just repeating the above process with a a different variable name `$picture_thumb = Upload::save($_FILES['picture']);`.  But that that did not work me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload::save() returns path to saved file, so just easily create new Image instance from it and save smaller version of Image. Something like:

```
$picture = Upload::save($_FILES['picture']);
// Resize, sharpen, and save the image
$image = Image::factory($picture)->resize(200, NULL);
$image->save();
$profile->profile_picture = basename($picture);



// Save thumbnail
$thumb_path = dirname($image->file).'/thumb_'.basename($image->file);
Image::factory($picture)->resize(100, NULL)->save($thumb_path); 
$profile->profile_picture_thumb = basename($thumb_path);
```

Comment: The thumbnail file does not save , but the db entry is there

Comment: nope

NOw I am getting error ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I see. It's because save returns just bool and not the path as Upload::save. It's fixed now, does it already works? :)

Comment: Thank You sir! greatly appreciate it and will learn from it